# how to create specific filename after reading file in mirth connect?

Tags: mirth

actually i'm reading file in `mirth connect>source transformer`, configuration is as you see in below image. There is file in `D:\yash.txt`, and after reading i want to move them into same directly by placing `_processed` suffix before `.txt` file extension.

[image]

file read and processed okay,it generate filename like `yash.txt_processed`, is there a way, i can give name like `yash_processed.txt`, i don't want to give it directly, because i want that whenever i add file into drive, it automatically processed. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your source connector create a JavaScript transformer step (click *Edit Transformer*) with the following code:

```
var srcFileName = sourceMap.get('originalFilename');
globalChannelMap.put('processedFile', srcFileName.replace(".", "_processed."));
```

Then, into the *Move-To File Name:* field place the newly created variable. So, instead of `${originalFilename}_processed` it should be `${processedFile}`

Try it now.

Comment: it's nice solution. it's same as i want. thank you buddy.

Comment: i want to understand NCPDP_D0 standard, do you have any great source, which help me to understand terminology, like for hl7, there are [corepoint](https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources)

Comment: in this, you simply use string.replace() method

Comment: For HIPAA transactions you probably need to go to CMS.gov site and look for specs there.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this...

```
var data = "processed";
channelMap.put("test",data);
```

[image]

put this channel map variable in the file writer location.

Comment: i'm not using destination transformer, i'm reading file from source connector in batch mode, and after processing, move that file to other location, btw thanks for your reply